# API Platform: Change embedded sub-resources to theirs @id

Tags: symfony, api-platform.com, symfony-4.3

I'm using Symfony 4.3 and API Platform 2.4. 
In my API there are resource 'groups' and related sub-resource 'phones':

```
{
    "@context": "/contexts/groups",
    "@id": "/groups/7116",
    "@type": "groups",
    "id": 7116,
    "name": "Standard Test",
    "description": "",
    "phones": {
        "7848412": {
            "@id": "/phones/7848412",
            "@type": "phones",
            "id": 7848412,
            "phone": "+412344545656",
            "a": "o2",
            "b": "",
            "c": "",
            "d": "",
            "e": ""
        }
}
```

Resources YAMLs:

```
entities\ClientPhoneGroup:
  shortName: 'groups'
  description: "Phone's group"
  collectionOperations:
    post:
      denormalization_context:
        groups: ['write']
  itemOperations:
    get: ~
    put:
      denormalization_context:
        groups: ['write']
    delete: ~

  attributes:
    normalization_context:
      groups: ['read']
    security: "is_granted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY')"
    subresource_operations:
      phone_get_subresource:
        method: 'GET'

  properties:
    id:
      identifier: true
    phones:
      subresource:
        resourceClass: 'entities\ClientPhone'
        collection: false
```

and

```
entities\ClientPhone:
  shortName: 'phones'
  description: "Phones list by group"
  collectionOperations:
    post:
      path: /groups/{group_id}/phones
      requirements:
        group_id: '\d+'
      denormalization_context:
        groups: ['write']
  itemOperations:
    get: ~
    put:
      denormalization_context:
        groups: ['write']
    delete: ~
  attributes:
    normalization_context:
      groups: ['read']
    security: "is_granted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY') "
```

serializers YAMLs:

```
entities\ClientPhoneGroup:
  attributes:
    id:
      groups: ['read']
    name:
      groups: ['read', 'write']
    description:
      groups: ['read', 'write']
    phones:
      groups: ['read']
```

and

```
entities\ClientPhone:
  attributes:
    id:
      groups: ['read']
    phone:
      groups: ['read', 'write', 'edit']
    a:
      groups: ['read', 'write', 'edit']
    b:
      groups: ['read', 'write', 'edit']
    c:
      groups: ['read', 'write', 'edit']
    d:
      groups: ['read', 'write', 'edit']
    e:
      groups: ['read', 'write', 'edit']
```

1. How to change embeded phones list to '/groups/7116/phones' in groups
   resource?
2. How to add link to 'group' resource (e.g. /groups/7116) to
   the phone sub-resource?

Answer (score 2):

Answer Question 2.
Remove `normalization_context:groups: ['read']`  from `entities\ClientPhone` so when you will call a GET group resource api, phone sub-resource will have IRI instead of all fields.